# Can I read MMS-s in Android KitKat without being the default messaging app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mms

On Android KitKat, if I'm not the default messaging app I can read the MMS-s? I only need to read them, not to send them. If yes, how? 
I've tried with

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.MMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but it didn't entered in `onReceive` `BroadcastReceiver` method at all when receiving a new MMS.

I know that with SMS this is doable: both to send and receive - under Kitkat without being default messaging app.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to include the BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH permission in the receiver.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.MMSReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />

        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is in addition to the use-permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
```